# Tutorials for box2d.xna?

Tags: c#, box2d, xna-4.0

I'm just starting with both C# and XNA and I wanted to know where I can get good beginner tutorials. I've already checked out box2d.org, but since I am a complete beginner with C# and XNA, I can't understand what code I have to put where.

**Update:**
I want to use box2d.xna instead of Farseer physics because I am making an Xbox game, and box2d.xna is optimized for Xbox. Farseer Physics can't get a decent frame rate on the Xbox, I've already tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend you to use box2d.xna it is outdated instead use farseerPhysics Engine witch is a port of box2d and is currently active: [Farseer Physics Engine](http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/)

I recently used it and was difficult to me to learn it.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm making an xbox 360 game, you can't get a decent frame rate with Farseer, already tried it. Box2d.xna is optimized for XBOX, that's why I want to use it. I should have mentioned that before. I'll still check out your example anyway, thanks.